# Falling Down Images

Tags: ios

I have this code on 3images (stars) goes down on my game. The difference between stars code is the delay timing on perform.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(star1Animation) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.0];
```

star1 = 2.0 seconds, star2 = 4.0 seconds and star3 = 6.0 seconds

Here the Code .m file

```
-(void)star1Animation
{
    // drop1 Down Movement Speed
    star1tm = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.01 target:self selector:@selector(star1Code) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) star1Code
{
    star1.center = CGPointMake(star1.center.x, star1.center.y +2);

    if (star1.center.y > 590) {
        ramdomPosition = arc4random() %265;
        ramdomPosition = ramdomPosition +54;        
        star1.center = CGPointMake(ramdomPosition, -60);

        // Time to Show drop1 Again in x Seconds
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop]runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2.0]];

    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.    

    [self performSelector:@selector(star1Animation) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.5];
    [self performSelector:@selector(star2Animation) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.5];
    [self performSelector:@selector(star3Animation) withObject:nil afterDelay:6.5];
}
```

Comment: You should really use something other than timers to do your animations. `[UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{ /* animation code here */ }];` would be a good first animation technique to try out.

Comment: Also, you are repeating yourself a lot with just a few small variations (what star and delay). Your code would be easier to grasp and maintain if you made *one* method with those two as arguments instead of the star1Code, star2Code, star3Code methods.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it better off on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to make three things animate at three different but related times is to use a single grouped animation (CAAnimationGroup). - As you've already been told, you should not be using timers or run loops to do the animations; instead, stop and learn how iOS animation actually works. It is built right into the system and is incredibly powerful; iOS *wants* to help you do animation, so instead of thwarting it and trying to "roll your own", learn how *it* does it and take advantage of its awesome power and ease of use.

You will also discover (if you will take the time to learn before coding) that in iOS 7, standard physics moves like "fall down" are greatly facilitated by UIKit Dynamics.

Comment: Here's the explanation of animation groups from my book - http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch17.html#_grouped_animations - but you really should start at the beginning of the chapter (perhaps at the beginning of the book).